# Regex to match whole words that begin with $

Tags: regex

I need a regex to match whole words that begin with $. What is the expression, and how can it be tested?

Example:

> This $word and $this should be extracted.

In the above sentence, `$word` and `$this` would be found.

Comment: Funny how `regex expression` is redundant... :-)

Comment: @tchrist a whole word is complete, as opposed to a partial word.

Answer (score 23):

If you want to match only whole words, you need the *word character selector*

```
\B\$\w+
```

This will match a `$` followed by one or more letters, numbers or underscore. [Try it out on Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/63s3ch1OYM)

Comment: Isn’t “isn’t” a word? How about “o’clock”? Is “side-effect” a word? Yes, yes, and yes. Is “42” a word?  What about “_____”?  No and no.

Comment: What I used was the regex definition of a word, which not surprisingly has a shortcut. That fits in with the examples in z-buffer's question. If he would clarify his definition of "whole word" as you asked, I can modify my answer to fit.

Comment: I agree that yours is the most natural solution in a programming context. It just doesn’t meet the definition of "word" most natural-language users would use. There are various refinements one can make on it, if one knows the target programming language. For example, Java adds `\p{Currency_Symbol}` to its allowed characters; some use `\p{ID_Start}\p{ID_Continue}*`; several languages admit `::` as a separator between classname and ident, etc. But without knowing what he really meant, it’s hard to do better I admit. The solution that questioned what to do about `$$foo` was also interesting.

Comment: This would also match the part beginning with the dollar sign in "aw$hucks". I think the question is how would you match words that only begin with the dollar sign.

Comment: Good point. You could add a `\B` word boundary selector at the beginning and it would work as you say.

Comment: maybe something is changed in regex, i found (here: http://regexr.com/) that \B is NOT start of the word, but \b should be used to match start of the word so resulting in: \b\$\w+

Comment: @pera, `$` is not a "word character" in regex, so its left boundary in this case needs to be a non-word to rule out `aw$hucks`. Since `w` is a word char, the boundary it shares with `$` is a word boundary. We need the opposite here.

Answer (score 18):

```
\$(\w+)
```

**Explanation :**

`\$` : escape the special `$` character
`()` : capture matches in here (in most engines at least)
`\w` : match `a - z`, `A - Z` and `0 - 9` (and`_`)
`+` : match it any number of times

Answer (score 5):

I think you want something like this:

```
/(^\$|(?<=\s)\$\w+)/
```

The first parentheses just captures your result.

^\$ matches the beginning of your entire string followed by a dollar sign;

| gives you a choice OR;

(?<=\s)\$ is a positive look behind that checks if there's a dollar sign   \$ with a space \s behind it.

Finally, (to recap) if we have a string that begins with a $ or a $ is preceded by a space, then the regex checks to see if one or more word characters follow - \w+.

This would match:

```
$test one two three
```

and

```
one two three $test one two three
```

but not

```
one two three$test
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But, i had to use it like this `/(^\@\w+|(?<=\s)\@\w+)/`

Answer (score 1):

For the testing part of you question I can recommend you using http://myregexp.com/

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Erikw. Please if what you want to say is not a direct answer for the question, post a comment on the question or one of the answers instead.

Comment: Was just thinking about this since I just noticed the comments. So an answer addressing only one part of a question is more suited as a comment?

Comment: My bad, I just noticed the "how can it be tested" part in the question. :) No, this is OK as it is.

Answer (score 0):

This should be self-explanatory:

```
\$\p{Alphabetic}[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Dash}\p{Quotation_Mark}]*(?<!\p{Dash})
```

Notice it doesn’t try to match digits or underscores are other silly things that words don’t have in them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as your regex:

```
/ (\$\w+)/
```

`\w+` means "one or more word characters". This matches anything beginning with $ followed by word characters, but only if it's preceded by a space.

You could test it with perl (the \ after the echo is just to break the long line):

```
> echo 'abc $def $ ghi $$jkl mnop' \
  | perl -ne 'while (/ (\$\w+)/g) {print "$1\n";} ' 
$def
```

If you don't use the space in the regex, you'll match the `$jkl` in `$$jkl` - not sure if that is what you want:

```
> echo 'abc $def $ ghi $$jkl mnop' \
  | perl -ne 'while (/(\$\w+)/g) {print "$1\n";} ' 
$def
$jkl
```