# Find/Replace specific string PHP until a space

Tags: php, string, loops, replace, str-replace

I'm trying to figure out how to find a string in PHP then delete all cocurrent letters after that string has been found until an eventual space.

Essentially in my app, I have a big text mixed with everything. For my outputs I want to remove any words that BEGINS with the character '@'.

For example string:

**This is a placeholder #string and it looks @great right?**

How do I search this string and remove only the "@great" part? I will not know what the @xxx would be so I first need to search the string then replace it with nothing.

I understand I can do this:

```
<?php
$string = "This is a placeholder #string and it looks @great right?";
$newstring = str_replace("@great", "", $string);
print $newstring;
?>
```

But I will not know what the @xxx will contain or how long it will be. What I would know is there will be an **eventual break/space** and thats all I want to remove.

So if the text contains a "@", find it along with all cocurrent letters until a space then remove the "@xxx" until the space. Leave everything else in tact.

Any ideas?

Comment: Google: regex word boundaries

Comment: Are you sure there will always be a space after it? What if it's the last word in the string? Can there be a punctuation mark at the end of it the @xxx, and if so, should that be removed as well?

Comment: What if there's an email on it? xD

Answer (score 2):

You can use preg_replace.

This will find the @ symbol and remove all letters or numbers after it plus one space.

```
$string = "This is a placeholder #string and it looks @great right?";
$newstring = preg_replace("/@\w+\s/", "", $string);
print $newstring;
```

https://3v4l.org/OUe87

Answer (score -1):

Method 1
combination of strpos() to locate the place in the original string and then substr() to return the string you want.
Method 2
You an also use explode() and use @great as delimiter and then analyse the returned array to get what you want

Comment: You need to give more details. It does answer the question to some degree, but you could give an example

Answer (score -1):

I found this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5877136/8695939

Same question but with **$**.

> \$(\w+)
>
> Explanation :
>
> \$ : escape the special $ character 
>   () : capture matches in here (in most engines at least) 
>   \w : match a - z, A - Z and 0 - 9 (and_) 
>   + : match it any number of times

Does it help ?

EDIT : With PHP [preg-replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Comment: Thanks it seems if I do \@(\w+) it can serve its purpose but how do I use regex in my context? In the context of find and replace?

Comment: Can I know why i have been downvoted ? I am here to help dudes..
I will edit my answer @Uz001